# Finding count of unique value before a character

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a some entries in database table rows as follows.

```
 101 - 1
 101 - 2
 101 - 3
 102 - 1
 102 - 2
 102 - 3
 103
```

I need to get the result of `SELECT` Query for count as '3' since there are `101` and `102` are the only number before the `-`.

So is there any way to find the unique value in db table columns before a character?

**EDIT :** I have entries even without the `-` .

Comment: Is that one row with lots of values in a column, or several columns, or several rows?

Comment: the entries are in several rows

Comment: first you need to split column base on "-" and store output in temp table and then use group by based on 1 column its will works..

Comment: Column data type? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: which sql you are using??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your entries have always the format you have provided us, you just have to find the position of the '-' character, split the values, get the first n characters and count the distinct values

This works for SQL Server, otherwise informs us about what DBMS you are using or replace the functions with the ones of your DBMS on your own

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING(val,0,CHARINDEX('-', val))) from YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table T1
(
    id int primary key identity,
    col1 varchar(20)
)

insert into T1 values('101 - 1'),('101 - 2'),('101 - 3'),('102 - 1'),('102 - 2'),('102 - 3')

select  SUBSTRING(col1,0,CHARINDEX(' ',col1)) as 'Value',count(*) as 'Count' from T1 group by SUBSTRING(col1,0,CHARINDEX(' ',col1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)